# How Can I get a value from a base class that has been declared as an Interface?

Tags: c#, oop, interface, abstract-class

This is an OOP based role-playing game. I am having trouble handling objects as interfaces.

```
abstract class Items
{
   public string name { get; set; }

}
```

all items have names, this is the property I am trying to get.

```
interface Ieatable
{
   int amountHealed { get; set; }
}
```

Will heal a player.

```
class Healers : Items, Ieatable
{

    private int heal;

    public int amountHealed
    {
        get { return heal; }
        set { heal = value; }
    }

    public Healers(int amount, string name)
    {
        heal = amount;
        base.name = name;
    }

}
```

Here is where I handle the eatable items. I go through each item in the players back pack. I then check if the item is eatable. Then the part I am struggling with, checking if one of the items in the players backpack is the same as the eatable item passed in as a parameter.

```
public void eatSomethingt(Ieatable eatable)
    {
        foreach (Items i in items ) //Go through every item(list) in the players backpack
        {
            if (i is Ieatable && i.name == eatable.name) //ERROR does not contain definition for name
            {
                Ieatable k = i as Ieatable;
                Console.WriteLine(Name + " ate " + eatable.name); //Same ERROR here.
                life = life + k.amountHealed;
                items.Remove(i);
                break;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Define `Name` property in interface

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the issue is. `Ieatable` does not have a definition for `name`. What are you confused about?

Comment: Try to avoid plurals. The class of all items should be `Item`.

Comment: I think you intended to say `as Items`, not `as Ieatable`.

Comment: @EricLippert No, `i` is already of type `Items` isn't it?

Comment: I totally understand the error. I just am not sure if that is the correct way to compare objects. Also, is it possible to have the interface extend the items class so I have access to the name variable.

Comment: He doesn't need do `i as Ieatable`. It's already Items, which has the properties he's using on k. Maybe he meant `i as Healers`, but that seems unnecessary too.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Ah, you are correct. I was misunderstanding the question.

Comment: So why not just add the name property to the definition of Ieatable?

Comment: @hatchet Don't know why OP ignored this, take a look at my first comment

Comment: @hatchet Is that an acceptable thing to do? Considering it's already defined in the main base class of `Items`

Comment: @user1743962 - the interface doesn't care who implements it. The interface is just a specification of some set of behavior. If Healers says it's Ieatable, it's just saying it can do those things. Whether it fulfills that promise through its own methods and properties or its base class' methods and properties, or a mix of both, doesn't really matter.

Comment: Change 'eatSomethingt(Ieatable)' to 'eatFirstItemFoundOfType(string)' and implement a way to check Ieatable against a type of item and your problems will go away.

Answer (score 3):

I would define it otherwise.

```
// The base interface for all items.
public interface INamedItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

// all classes are derived from INamedItem, so you can always have the Name property.
public interface IEatable : INamedItem
{
    int AmountHealed { get; set; }
}

public class Healers : Ieatable
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int AmountHealed { get; set; }

    public Healers(int amountHealed, string name)
    {
        AmountHealed = amountHealed;
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

example:

```
public void eatSomethingt(IEatable eatable)
{
    var eatItem = items.OfType<IEatable>.Where( item => item.Name == eatable.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (eatItem == null)
        return;

    life = life + eatItem.amountHealed;
    Console.WriteLine(Name + " ate " + eatable.name); //Same ERROR here.
    items.Remove(i);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change your design as the other answers indicated to make your `EatSomething` method work.  Simply change the type of what is passed:

```
public void eatSomethingt(Healer healer)
{
    foreach (Items i in items)
    {
        if (i is Ieatable && i.name == healer.name)
        {
            Ieatable k = i as Ieatable;
            Console.WriteLine(Name + " ate " + healer.name);
            life = life + k.amountHealed;
            items.Remove(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The caveat to this answer is that you may have a need for something that is `IEatable`, but not an `Item` (or `Healer`).  In that case, however, you may not have a name to compare against anyway, thus needing a separate method.

Where does the `IEatable` you are passing to the method come from?  I would assume it originates from a mouse click on the inventory item, thus, you could do something like this:

```
public void eatSomethingt(Healer item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Name + " ate " + item.name);
    life = life + item.amountHealed;
    items.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface on Items

```
interface IITems
{
    string name { get; set; }
}

abstract class Items : IItems
{ ....
```

Then use it in IEatable

```
public interface IEatable : IItems
{ ....
```

Then healers class:

```
public class Healers : IEatable
{ ...
```

Then you should be able to access name property of type IEatable